# Get template parameter from boost::ptr_vector

Tags: c++, boost, ptr-vector

From `boost::ptr_vector<T>` I am trying to get `T`, but `boost::ptr_vector<T>::value_type` seems to be `T*`. How can I get `T`?

Looking at the doc, I see:

```
typedef  T*                                           value_type;
typedef  T&                                           reference;
typedef  const T&                                     const_reference;
```

None of which help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Boost, you can use [`boost::remove_pointer`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/remove_pointer.html) to get the pointed-to type.

```
boost::remove_pointer<boost::ptr_vector<T>::value_type>::type
```

will evaluate to `T`.

If you can use C++11 features, you could use `std::remove_pointer` in the same manner as Boost's version.

Comment: There's boost::remove_pointer which you can guarantee he has if he's using Boost, and it's trivial to write yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++11, [std::remove_pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer) on `value_type` should do the job.